# ViewPager - FragmentStatePagerAdapter and handling rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` which holds `Fragment`s. `ViewPager` has an adapter of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Adapter's `getItem` method.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    String text= dbHelper.getText(position);
    CustomFragment frg = new CustomFragment(text);
    return frg;
}
```

I am initializing the fragment in the `getItem` method of the adapter.

Everything works perfectly.

When the orientation changes however, instead of restoring my initialized fragments, `CustomFragment`s are created using the default constructor of `CustomFragment`. So this creates fragments with dummy data.

What is the reason of this?
How can i restore the previously created fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way to initialise your `Fragment`s is to create a factory method like:

```
public static CustomFragment newInstance(String text) {
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.put("someText", text);

    CustomFragment fragment = new CustomFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);

    return fragment;
}
```

and get the arguments with `getArguments()` in the `onCreate()` method and process it to initialise whatever you want in the fragment.

This way when your fragments are recreated on configuration change, the arguments are persisted and the `Fragment`s take care of themselves when their `onCreate()` method is called.

You might have noticed the lint warnings about the same if you are using the latest tools.

Comment: @salih-erikci Did you give it a try?

Comment: Yes, i used your method and it worked. As you said this must be the ideal and recommended way to initialize fragments. Thanks